# Change logging level of spring framework

Tags: java, spring, logging

I am implementing a client of rest api by using Resttemplate of spring framework. The program is simple which just sends a Get request to the server. When I run the program, a lot of messages shows, something like:

12:58:40.149 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match 12:58:40.157 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context

Does anyone know how to remove these messages when I run the program? BTW, I am using gradle to build my project.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, this has to do with your logging framework and how you configure it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add to your log4j.properties file ( probably in src/main/resources ) line like:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO
```

so it will only print those messages on 'INFO' level